# Kia Sorento 2008 CRDi ESP Off Light

Tags: kia, 4wd, esp-esc

I've recently bought this car, it was fine for a couple of days and suddenly the ESP Off light showed up and it won't turn on when pressing the ESP button. you have to turn off the ignition and then start again. Searching online many people have had the same problem.

many suspected it's the brake light switch which is failing and causing the ESP to fail too as they are sharing some circuits.

However, I am not still convinced this is the issue as the brake lights perfectly work when you press the pedal.

also, I am not getting any errors . any idea what's happening here?

Similar cases:

https://forum.australia4wd.com/index.php?/topic/16730-esp-light/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the brakes work, it does not mean the brake light switch is working properly.
The brake light swtich has several "switches" inside. [This article explains the brake light switch and how it works.](https://www.youcanic.com/article/brake-light-switch-problems-causes-tips)

I would recommend that instead of replacing random parts, you get the ABS codes read. You can't use a generic scanner. You will need a scanner that can read abs codes. Such a scanner will cost you $100+ or have a local mechanic scan the codes for about .5 hour labour.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so you believe the ESP Off light is caused by Brake light switch malfunction?

Comment: It is very possible. The bottom line is that you need to scan the codes.

Comment: Just for the future reference, changed the brake pads and the ESP off Light never appeared again.